# std::is_invocable is false but std::invoke works

Tags: c++, c++17

The following program's output seems to contradict itself:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo(int&){ std::cout << "called\n"; }

int main() {
    int a;
    foo(a);
    std::cout << std::is_invocable_v<decltype(foo), decltype(a)> << std::endl;
    std::invoke(foo, a);
}
```

The output is:

```
called
0
called
```

Which seems to me to be invoking a function that is not invocable? What is going on here?

Comment: Based of a hunch, does it change if `foo` accepts a const lvalue reference instead?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d8a4615fda8e8b4), but can you explain why?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[`decltype(a)` is `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype). This corresponds to invoking `f` with an `int` *prvalue* -- something like `f(7)`. That one indeed doesn't compile, because a non-`const` lvalue reference cannot bind to a prvalue.

What you're doing instead in `main` is calling `f` with an *lvalue*, `a`, to which the reference can bind just fine.

To get the correct result from `std::is_invocable`, use the expression form of `decltype` by adding parentheses:

```
std::is_invocable_v<decltype(foo), decltype((a))>
//                                          ^ ^
```

Comment: Or use `decltype((a))` in this case :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, definitely. I don't know why this escaped me.

Comment: If `int` means a *prvalue* int, wouldn't that make `a` an *xvalue*, since it is a named *prvalue*? Or am I all confused about the nature of the value categories?

Comment: @baruch Yes you are ;-) a is a simple lvalue.

Comment: @baruch Value categories are properties of expressions, not properties of types. You can have expressions of type `int` that are lvalues (e.g. `a`), xvalues (e.g. `std::move(a)`) or prvalues (e.g. `a + 1`).

Comment: Xvalue, not prvalue. We're checking if we can invoke `f(declval<int>())`.

Comment: @barry ooo, `struct no_move{ explicit no_move(int) {} no_move(no_move&&)=delete; }; void f(no_move){}` -- how can we test if `no_move` can be called with a prvalue, as opposed to an xvalue?  `f( []()->no_move{ return no_move(1); }() )`.

Comment: @Yakk isn't `f(no_move(1))` enough, or is there a point to the lambda?

Comment: @Quentin True: I was thinking of ways to "transport" prvalues from one context to another, which does require something lambda like (as you cannot carry around a prvalue, but you can carry around something that when invoked produces a prvalue).  After thinking it over, I've asked a SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48174588/1774667) with your exact simplification.