# How do we test if an expression of a certain type can be invoked with a prvalue?

Tags: c++, c++17, prvalue, declval, invocable

With [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) we have fancy new [`is_invocable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) and fancy new prvalues that aren't really values.

This permits you to create an object without having to first logically construct it, then elide the construction.

I have run into a problem where using `std::is_invocable` to test if you can call something, and prvalue rules, seem to collide:

```
struct no_move {
  no_move(no_move&&)=delete;
  explicit no_move(int) {}
};
void f( no_move ) {}
```

now can we ask if `f` can be invoked using a prvalue of type `no_move`?

```
f( no_move(1) )
```

`std::is_invocable< decltype(&f), no_move >` doesn't work because it uses `std::declval<no_move>()` which is an xvalue like `no_move&&` not a prvalue of type `no_move`.

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) this was the same, but guaranteed elision makes some functions callable with an xvalue (i.e., "`T&&`") and others with prvalues of type `T`.

Is there an alternative, or do we have to invent our own trait to handle this case?

(In a theoretical world where `std::declval<T>` returned `T` instead of `T&&`, `is_invocable` would, I believe, do the right thing).

Comment: Maybe `std::declval` is now broken, and needs to return exactly what was passed in?

Comment: @Quentin `std::declval2` maybe.  Or `std2::declval`.  But yes, a `std::declval<T>` that returned `T` would make `std::is_invocable` be able to answer the above question.  That falls under "invent our own trait" at this point.  I wonder if any existing [tag:C++14] code would break if `declval<T>()` returned `T`?

Comment: @Yakk This is pretty strange, I don't know why they just didn't allow `std::declval<T>` to return exactly a `T`; if that were the case then you can still do `declval<T&&>` to do what current declval does, but by adding the reference for us it makes it impossible to "construct" the value type.

Comment: @NirFriedman Requirements that `T` can be destroyed are then added to `std::declval<T>` based tests.  So there is that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an alternative, or do we have to invent our own trait to handle this case?

Yeah, you'd just have to write your own trait that doesn't use `declval`. Assuming you have [`std::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) lying around (which I know you certainly do):

```
template <typename T> T make();

template <typename F, typename... Args>
using invoke_result_t = decltype(std::declval<F>()(make<Args>()...));
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^

template <typename F, typename... Args>
using is_invocable = std::is_detected<invoke_result_t, F, Args...>;
```

This way, `std::is_invocable<decltype(f), no_move>` is `false_type`, but `is_invocable<decltype(f), no_move)>` is `true_type`.

I intentionally use `declval<F>()` for the function instead of `make` so as to allow using `decltype(f)` here. Really, `invoke_result_t` should be more complicated, and "do the right thing" for pointers to members, etc. But this is at least a simple approximation that indicates the viability of this approach.

Comment: It's not clear to me how useful this knowledge is, though.

Comment: @T.C. Maybe you have a function template which takes a callable, and the body calls it with a prvalue? It could happen.

Comment: @Barry: But the point behind "invocable" is that you're going to call `std::invoke`. That's why member pointers are invocable; because you can use `std::invoke` on them. You can't call them with `()`.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's because `std::invoke()` was the wrong way to solve the problem, and we should've made pointers-to-members invocable by actually making them invocable. I tried.

Answer (score 7):

You are misusing the Invocable concept. This concept means nothing more than the ability to use `std::invoke` on the given function and the provided arguments.

You can't do `std::invoke(f, no_move(1))`, as this would provoke a copy/move of the forwarded argument. It is impossible for a prvalue to be used as a parameter through a forwarded call like `invoke`. You can pass a prvalue to the forwarding call, but the eventual call to the given function will get an xvalue.

This is a good reason to avoid using immobile types as value parameters in functions. Take them by `const&` instead.

C++ does not have a type trait to see if a function can be called with specific parameters in the way that you want.